# Apply solid white color to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to apply solid white background color, so that the text behind it should not be visible.

Attaching screenshot for reference.
[image]

So, basically I have a header with a dropdown and when I am clicking on the dropdown the text from the body is visible at the back.

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: set dropdown's container style to `background-color: #fff;`

Comment: Does the dropdown not have a background or is the dropdown being overlapped by the content?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: please provide the code you're working with currently.

Comment: @Addis Added css code for dropdown-menu

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, that's some personal code. I can't post it.

Comment: please add your html too?

Comment: Of course you can post code, just use dummy non-private text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that by keeping `mix-blend-mode` to `unset`.